# Files added to tarfile come back as empty files

Tags: python

I am trying to add a file to a gzipped tarfile in python

```
import tarfile

# create test file
with open("testfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("TESTTESTTEST")

# create archive
with tarfile.open("archfile.tar.gz", "x:gz") as archive:
    with open("testfile.txt", 'rb') as f:
        archive.addfile(tarfile.TarInfo("testfile.txt"), f)

# read test file out of archive
with tarfile.open("archfile.tar.gz", "r:gz") as archive:
    print(archive.extractfile("testfile.txt").read())
```

The result is `b''` - an empty bytestring.

The file is not empty - if I try to read the file using the following code:

```
with open("testfile.txt", 'rb') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

... I get `b'TESTTESTTEST'`

Is there something obvious I am missing? My end goal is to add the string in memory using `f = io.StringIO('TESTTESTTEST')`

I also tried removing the `:gz` and I see the same problem with a raw tar archive.

For additional info - I'm using Python 3 in a jupyter session on Windows 10. I see the same problem in Windows/Python 3.5.2/PyCharm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hit a similar problem. The documentation says that when you call `tar.addfile` it will write `TarInfo.size` bytes from the given file. That means that you have to either create the `TarInfo` with the file size or use `tar.add()` instead of `tar.addfile`:

```
# create archive V1
with tarfile.open("archfile.tar.gz", "x:gz") as archive:
    with open("testfile.txt", 'rb') as f:
        info = archive.gettarinfo("testfile.txt")
        archive.addfile(info, f)

# create archive V2
with tarfile.open("archfile.tar.gz", "x:gz") as archive:
    archive.add("testfile.txt")

# create archive V3
with tarfile.open("archfile.tar.gz", "w:gz") as archive:
    with io.BytesIO(b"TESTTESTTEST") as f:
        info = tarfile.TarInfo("testfile.txt")
        f.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
        info.size = f.tell()
        f.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
        archive.addfile(info, f)
```

Comment: This is great - the key thing was that I was not adding the file size to the `TarInfo`. Thank you. Annoyingly to do this with a `BytesIO` object you seem to have to use `info.size = f.write("TESTTESTTEST")` and then `f.seek(0)`, but I finally got it working.

Comment: THANK YOU, been trying to figure it out for hours

Comment: **Create archive V3** was what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can us the StringIO module to write the content as a file object to the tar file.

**Sample:**

```
import tarfile
import StringIO

tar = tarfile.TarFile("archfile.tar.gz","w")
with open("testfile.txt", 'rb') as f:
    s = StringIO.StringIO(f.read())

info = tarfile.TarInfo(name="testfile.txt")
info.size = len(s.buf)
tar.addfile(tarinfo=info, fileobj=s)
tar.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Creating a tar archive using tarfile

If you create a tar archive it is critical that the `TarInfo` object contains the file size, otherwise you will create files in the archive with no data. The easiest solution is to use `gettarinfo` which has the function signature

> TarFile.gettarinfo(name=None, arcname=None, fileobj=None)`

Given the open file object it will determine the size. With the correctly create `TarInfo` object `addfile` will copy in the bytes.

```
import tarfile

with tarfile.open('Archive.tar.xz', mode='w:xz') as t:
    for file_path in file_paths:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            info = t.gettarinfo(fileobj=f)
            t.addfile(tarinfo=info, fileobj=f)
```

Answer (score -1):

Not a perfect answer but I managed to work around this with zipfile.

```
import zipfile
import io

# create archive
with zipfile.ZipFile("archfile.zip", "w") as archive:
    with io.StringIO("TESTTESTTEST") as f:
        archive.writestr("1234.txt", f.read())

# read test file out of archive
with zipfile.ZipFile("archfile.zip", "r") as archive:
    print(archive.read("1234.txt"))
```

produces `b'TESTTESTTEST'`